# How can I run command automatically in 'shellinabox'?

Tags: shell, automation

I wanna make auto login and auto scripts in 'shellinabox' web.

The way

> "https://IPAdress:Port?u=xxx&p=yyy"

doesn't work.

someone says "use shell script like mySSHlogin.sh", but I can't find information about that.

How can I run command automatically?

and can I use 'Expect' in here?

> expect "password: " send {"password\r"}

doesn't work.

my shellinabox version is 2.14 and I use Ubuntu.